# AWS Console Elastic Beanstalk Monitoring tab is empty, Previously it was displayig metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have multiple Elastic Beanstalk apps in two aws accounts. In one of them for all 3 elastic beanstalk apps, Monitoring tab is empty for some reason. In other is displaying metrics as earlier. I do not recall any significant change that could be a reason for this or find any setting that does this. Below is a screenshot of Monitoring tab.

Any pointers, indicators to get it resolve would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you check your IAM Service-Linked Roles for Elastic Beanstalk:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/iam-servicerole.html#iam-servicerole-slr
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-service-linked-roles-monitoring.html

There is a specific Service-Linked role for monitoring, and also a procedure for [updating an out-of-date default service role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/iam-servicerole.html#iam-servicerole-update). It's possible that the role you are using could lack some of the required permissions.

The general guidance from AWS on that is essentially to create a new EB environment or add the missing permissions to the role by appending policies to that role:

> If the default service role lacks the required permissions, you can update it by creating a new environment in the Elastic Beanstalk environment management console.
> Alternatively, you can manually add the managed policies to the default service role.